# How to solve the error message: crtmfcpatch.h not found?

Tags: c, visual-studio, hash

[image: error message: crtmfcpatch.h not found]

I'm creating my own C hash table implementation. It still has some errors and I'm in the process of debugging, but I get hung up on this error message in the picture. It has to do with <vld.h> which I'm using to check for memory leaks. I'm not sure what it means. The error happens on line 68 of my HashTable.c file (the malloc right after "if (overflow)" and as far as I can tell, the malloc looks fine. I copied and pasted all code if someone needs to run it. 3 header files, 2 implementation files, and a main.c file

I'm well aware my code could have other problems so this isn't a question about implementing a correct hash table. It's specifically about this error message as it relates to vld.h. Also, vld.h is a leak detector for Microsoft Visual Studio.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

status.h

```
#ifndef STATUS_H
#define STATUS_H

typedef enum status { FAILURE, SUCCESS } Status;
typedef enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE } Boolean;

#endif
```

HashTable.h

```
#ifndef HASH_TABLE_H
#define HASH_TABLE_H

#include "status.h"
typedef void* HASH_TABLE;

/* Precondition: none
   Postcondition: returns a handle to an empty hash table or NULL on Failure */
HASH_TABLE hash_table_init_default(unsigned initial_capacity);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a valid hash_table
   Postcondition: returns an index in the hash table that comes from
   hasing the key with the hash table capacity */
unsigned hash_table_hash(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a valid hash_table
   Postcondition: returns the capacity */
unsigned hash_table_get_capacity(HASH_TABLE hHash_table);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a valid hash table. Key and data
   are the info to be put into the hash_table
   Postcondition: a new element has been created and inserted in the hash table
   Returns FAILURE for any memory allocation failure */
Status hash_table_insert(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, int data);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a valid hash table object. Key is the
   key to search for.
   Postcondition: if the key exists, stores it in data and returns SUCCESS. Else,
   returns FAILURE and stores a 0 in data */
Status hash_table_get_data_by_key(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, int* data);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a hash table. key is the key to be looked for.
   Postcondition: if the key exists, stores the index in indexOfKey and returns true. If it
   doesn't, returns false and stors a 0 in indexOfKey */
Boolean hash_table_get_key_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, unsigned* indexOfKey);


Status hash_table_get_data_by_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, int index, int* data);

Status hash_table_get_key_by_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, int index, char* key);

/* Precondition: hHash_table is a handle to a valid hash table object. Key is the
   key to be searched for
   Postcondition: if the element corresponding to the key exists, it is removed and
   SUCCESS is returned. Else, it FAILURE is returned */
Status hash_table_remove_element(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key);

/* Precondition: phHash_table is a pointer to a handle to a hash table
   Postcondion: all memory associated with the hash table has been freed.
   and the hash table handle is set to NULL */
void hash_table_destroy(HASH_TABLE* phHash_table);

#endif
```

HashTableElement.h

```
#ifndef KEY_AND_DATA_H
#define KEY_AND_DATA_H

#include "status.h"

typedef void* HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT;

/*Precondition: none
  Postcondition: returns a handle to a new hash table element. Else returns NULL */
HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hash_table_element_create(char* key, int data);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element, data is the
  new data value.
  Postcondition: the data inside the hash table has been updated. */
void hash_table_element_update(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element, int data);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element.
  Postcondition: returns the data value. */
int hash_table_element_get_data(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element.
  Postcondition: returns the key */
const char* hash_table_element_get_key(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element1 and 2 are handles to valid hash table elements. 
  Postcondition: returns true or false if the keys match or not*/
Boolean hash_table_element_keys_match(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element1,
    HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element2);

Status hash_table_element_get_character_by_index(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element, int index, char* ch);

void hash_table_element_destroy(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT* phHash_table_element);

#endif
```

HashTable.c

```
#include "HashTable.h"
#include "HashTableElement.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vld.h>


typedef struct hash_table {
    HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT* table;
    unsigned capacity;
} Hash_table;


HASH_TABLE hash_table_init_default(unsigned initial_capacity) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)malloc(sizeof(Hash_table));
    if (pHash_table != NULL) {
        pHash_table->table = (HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT) * initial_capacity);
        if (pHash_table->table == NULL) {
            free(pHash_table);
            return NULL;
        }
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < initial_capacity; i++) {
            pHash_table->table[i] = NULL;
        }
        pHash_table->capacity = initial_capacity;
    }
    return (HASH_TABLE)pHash_table;
}


unsigned hash_table_hash(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
    unsigned sum = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        sum += key[i];
    return sum % pHash_table->capacity;
}

unsigned hash_table_get_capacity(HASH_TABLE hHash_table) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
    return pHash_table->capacity;
}

Status hash_table_insert(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, int data) {
    unsigned index = hash_table_hash(hHash_table, key);
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;

    unsigned quadraticNum = 1;
    Boolean overflow = FALSE;
    while (pHash_table->table[index] != NULL) {
        if (index >= pHash_table->capacity) {
            overflow = TRUE;
            break;
        }
        else if (!strcmp(hash_table_element_get_key(pHash_table->table[index]), key)) {
            hash_table_element_update(pHash_table->table[index], data);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
            index += quadraticNum * quadraticNum;
            quadraticNum++;
        }
    }

    if (overflow) {
        unsigned newCapacity = index + 1;
        HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT* newTable = (HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT) * newCapacity);
        if (newTable == NULL)
            return FAILURE;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < pHash_table->capacity; i++) {
            if (pHash_table->table[i] == NULL)
                newTable[i] = NULL;
            else {
                newTable[i] =
                    hash_table_element_create(hash_table_element_get_key(pHash_table->table[i]),
                        hash_table_element_get_data(pHash_table->table[i]));
                if (newTable[i] == NULL) {
                    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                        hash_table_element_destroy(&(newTable[j]));
                    free(newTable);
                    return FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }

        for (unsigned i = pHash_table->capacity; i < newCapacity - 1; i++)
            newTable[i] = NULL;

        newTable[newCapacity - 1] = hash_table_element_create(key, data);
        if (newTable[newCapacity - 1] == NULL) {
            for (int i = newCapacity - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                hash_table_element_destroy(&(newTable[i]));
            free(newTable);
            return FAILURE;
        }
        free(pHash_table->table);
        pHash_table->table = newTable;
        pHash_table->capacity = newCapacity;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    else {
        pHash_table->table[index] = hash_table_element_create(key, data);
        if (pHash_table->table[index] == NULL)
            return FAILURE;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

Boolean hash_table_get_key_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, unsigned* indexOfKey) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
    unsigned index = hash_table_hash(hHash_table, key);
    unsigned quadraticNum = 1;
    while (index < pHash_table->capacity) {
        if (pHash_table->table[index] != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(key, hash_table_element_get_key(pHash_table->table[index]))) {
                *indexOfKey = index;
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        index += quadraticNum * quadraticNum;
        quadraticNum++;
    }
    *indexOfKey = 0;
    return FALSE;
}

Status hash_table_get_data_by_key(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key, int* data) {
    unsigned indexOfKey = 0;
    if (hash_table_get_key_index(hHash_table, key, &indexOfKey)) {
        Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
        *data = hash_table_element_get_data(pHash_table->table[indexOfKey]);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    *data = 0;
    return FAILURE;
}

Status hash_table_get_data_by_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, int index, int* data) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
    if (index >= pHash_table->capacity || pHash_table->table[index] == NULL) {
        *data = 0;
        return FAILURE;
    }
    *data = hash_table_element_get_data(pHash_table->table[index]);
    return SUCCESS;
}


Status hash_table_get_key_by_index(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, int index, char* key) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
    if (index >= pHash_table->capacity || pHash_table->table[index] == NULL) {
        key[0] = '\0';
        return FAILURE;
    }

    char ch;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(hash_table_element_get_key(pHash_table->table[index])); i++) {
        hash_table_element_get_character_by_index(pHash_table->table[index], i, &key[i]);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

Status hash_table_remove_element(HASH_TABLE hHash_table, char* key) {
    unsigned indexOfKey = 0;
    if (hash_table_get_key_index(hHash_table, key, &indexOfKey)) {
        Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)hHash_table;
        hash_table_element_destroy(&(pHash_table->table[indexOfKey]));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return FAILURE;
}


void hash_table_destroy(HASH_TABLE* phHash_table) {
    Hash_table* pHash_table = (Hash_table*)*phHash_table;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pHash_table->capacity; i++)
        hash_table_element_destroy(&(pHash_table->table[i]));
    free(pHash_table->table);
    free(pHash_table);
    *phHash_table = NULL;
}
```

HashTableElement.c

```
#ifndef KEY_AND_DATA_H
#define KEY_AND_DATA_H

#include "status.h"

typedef void* HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT;

/*Precondition: none
  Postcondition: returns a handle to a new hash table element. Else returns NULL */
HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hash_table_element_create(char* key, int data);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element, data is the
  new data value.
  Postcondition: the data inside the hash table has been updated. */
void hash_table_element_update(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element, int data);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element.
  Postcondition: returns the data value. */
int hash_table_element_get_data(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element is a handle to a valid hash table element.
  Postcondition: returns the key */
const char* hash_table_element_get_key(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element);

/*Precondition: hHash_table_element1 and 2 are handles to valid hash table elements. 
  Postcondition: returns true or false if the keys match or not*/
Boolean hash_table_element_keys_match(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element1,
    HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element2);

Status hash_table_element_get_character_by_index(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT hHash_table_element, int index, char* ch);

void hash_table_element_destroy(HASH_TABLE_ELEMENT* phHash_table_element);

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HashTable.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <vld.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    HASH_TABLE hHash_table = hash_table_init_default(5);
    char key[2] = "A";
    unsigned num = 1;

    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hash_table_insert(hHash_table, key, num);
        key[0] = key[0] + 1;
        num++;
    }

    int data;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < hash_table_get_capacity(hHash_table); i++) {
        hash_table_get_key_by_index(hHash_table, i, key);
        hash_table_get_data_by_index(hHash_table, i, &data);
        printf("%s %d\n", key, data);
    }

    key[0] = 'F';
    hash_table_insert(hHash_table, key, num);
    num++;

    hash_table_destroy(&hHash_table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you, perhaps, trying to step into the "vld" library while debugging? Maybe your library was compiled with debugging symbols on, but you do not have the source code (??) *Just brain-storming here*

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. Yes, you are correct. It only happens when I go into debug mode. That solves my problem thank you. Could you elaborate more on why this is?

Comment: *hand-waving all through this comment...* when a library (dll, whatever) is compiled with debugging symbols on and you step into it, the debugger knows what file and line to show. Some libraries are available in both "debug" and "release" versions... having the "debug" version only really makes sense with the source code. If you step into library code with no debugging info, the debugger will probably only show machine code. --- so `crtmfcpatch.h` is available for the developers of the library, but not you: you should maybe use a release version

Comment: Thanks, I sort of get that. I'm not too well versed in the "behind the scenes" things of programming but that makes general sense.

Comment: ... or the library info says the files are on `C:/vld/src/...` but when you installed they went into `C:/users/ben/vld/src/...` and the debugger cannot find the source files.